# The size of Graph file(.pb) from Tensorflow is too large for android Usage, how to reduce it?

Tags: android, tensorflow

I try to build a network implementing the Yolo Object detection using tensorflow, and I want it could be used on Android. After building the structure, I use the tf.train.write_graph to get the graph file and want to replace the original file in android demo.
 But the pb file is too large (1.1G) which is not usable on Android. So, how could I reduce the size?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to first try quantizing your graph, for that you'll only need an official TensorFlow script. Here's a great tutorial by Pete Warden:
https://petewarden.com/2016/05/03/how-to-quantize-neural-networks-with-tensorflow/

In theory if you used 32 bit floats your model is going to end up ~4 times (~250Mb) smaller since the values in the graph will be converted to 8 bit integers (For inference it has no significant effect on the performance). Note that this comes into play when you compress the Protocol Buffer file.